# Добавление функционала в метод

Tags: android, kotlin

Как в данный метод

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (numpadView?.visible ?: false) closeNumpadView() else activity?.finishFragment()
}
```

можно засунуть ещё одну функцию `testView?.clearFocus()` таким образом чтоб она работала?

Comment: а в чём проблема возникает, когда помещается как обычно?

Comment: тем что не срабатывает он почему-то, хотя должен по идее.

Comment: хм. видимо не достаточно данных в вопросе, если просто поместить в тело метода, то код выполнится, но не сработает, что-то другое

Comment: А вы можете проверить что происходит при скрытии клавиатуры? То есть получаете какую то нотификацию или нет?